# Radeon 6500XT Graphics not working when installing or booting Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, amd-graphics, amdgpu

I have a new desktop with an AMD Radeon RX 6500 XT graphics card. I have a 4K screen attached via HDMI, and ubuntu boots to a black screen. I installed Ubuntu 22.04 (using safemode graphics) and managed to get the machine to boot successfully using the nomodeset kernel parameter (which uses the llvmpipe driver).

This is a pure Ubuntu system (no other OS). I've tried upgrading the kernel to 5.17, which didn't work. AMD Pro drivers are currently unavailable for 22.04 so not sure what to try next.

Edit: Have looked at updating UEFI, but it's already up to date. I'm using an Asus Prime B550 Plus motherboard with firmware version 2604. I've also made sure that secure boot is disabled.

Comment: It should work with the standard kernel shipped with Ubuntu 22.04 and the open-source drivers. If it doesn't what you should do before anything else is update UEFI and then check possible settings there that have to be changed. The solution is neither unsupported kernel nor the AMD proprietary overlay.

Comment: Check the contents of /var/log/Xorg.0.log Xorg.1.log etc and /var/log/syslog (kernlog) there's usually traces there of what failed (when booting with mesa drivers)

Comment: Does this problem also happen to the liveusb?

Comment: Yup happens with the liveusb as well.

Comment: @ChanganAuto UEFI might the the answer given it fails regardless of kernel version. I'll try it on Monday and update here

Comment: @ChanganAuto unfortunately the BIOS is up to date.

Comment: Standard kernel driver for 6500xt in Ubuntu 22.04 unfortunately is very buggy. Still waiting for amd official driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in my case was not the kernel drivers, but a dodgy HDML cable that couldn't reliably support 4K@60Hz. Swapping out for a displayport cable fixed the problem.